# Makefile error: boost/asio.hpp: No such file or directory (Windows)

Tags: c++, linux, boost, makefile

I have a C++ program, that compiles fine on Linux. But when I tried to compile it on Windows, I got: `fatal error: boost/asio.hpp: No such file or directory`.
I don't understand how is that possible, since I have few more boost includes (`<boost/thread.hpp>` and `<boost/locale.hpp>`) and they work fine. I also checked in my boost library, and `thread.hpp`, `locale.hpp` and `asio.hpp` are all there.
If that matters, on Linux I installed boost with the following commands (and it works there):

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install aptitude
aptitude search boost
```

And this is my code:

Client.cpp:

```
#include "../include/ConnectionHandler.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

 //A method used to read messages from the console (stdin) and send them to the server using a ConnectionHandler 
void sendMessage(ConnectionHandler *connectionHandler){ // handles stdin
    if (connectionHandler->isConnected()){
        while (1){
            const short bufsize = 1024;
            char buf[bufsize];
            std::cin.getline(buf, bufsize);
            std::string line(buf);
            if (!connectionHandler->sendLine(line)) { break; }
            if (line=="QUIT"){
                boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
                if (!connectionHandler->isConnected()) { break; }
            }
        }
    }
}

//A method used to read messages from the socket (using the ConnectionHandler)
void recieveMessage(ConnectionHandler *connectionHandler){ // handles socket
    while (1){
        std::string answer;
        if (!connectionHandler->getLine(answer)) {
            std::cout << "Disconnected.\nExiting...\n" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        int len=answer.length();
        answer.resize(len-1);
        std::cout << answer << std::endl << std::endl; // double line drops so it will be easier to notice between messages
        if (answer == "SYSMSG QUIT ACCEPTED") {
            std::cout << "Disconnected.\nExiting...\n" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    (*connectionHandler).close();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " host port" << std::endl << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::string host = argv[1];
    unsigned short port_ = atoi(argv[2]);
    ConnectionHandler *connectionHandler_= new ConnectionHandler(host,port_);
    if (!(connectionHandler_)->connect()) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot connect to " << host << ":" << port_ << std::endl;
        delete connectionHandler_;
        return 1;
    }
    boost::thread sender(&sendMessage,connectionHandler_); // a different thread to handle stdin
    boost::thread reciever(&recieveMessage,connectionHandler_); // a different thread to handle the socket
    reciever.join();
    sender.join();
    delete connectionHandler_;
}
```

ConnectionHandler.h:

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_HANDLER__
#define CONNECTION_HANDLER__

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class ConnectionHandler {
private:
    const std::string host_;
    const short port_;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_;   // Provides core I/O functionality
    tcp::socket socket_;
    bool isConnected_;

public:
    ConnectionHandler(std::string host, short port);
    virtual ~ConnectionHandler();

    bool connect();
    bool getBytes(char bytes[], unsigned int bytesToRead);
    bool sendBytes(const char bytes[], int bytesToWrite);
    bool getLine(std::string& line);
    bool sendLine(std::string& line);
    bool getFrameAscii(std::string& frame, char delimiter);
    bool sendFrameAscii(const std::string& frame, char delimiter);
    void close();
    bool isConnected();
}; 

#endif
```

ConnectionHandler.cpp:

```
#include "../include/ConnectionHandler.h"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

ConnectionHandler::ConnectionHandler(string host, short port): host_(host), port_(port), io_service_(), socket_(io_service_), isConnected_(false){}

ConnectionHandler::~ConnectionHandler() { close(); }

bool ConnectionHandler::connect() {
    std::cout << "Starting connect to " << host_ << ":" << port_ << std::endl;
    try {
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host_), port_); // the server endpoint
        boost::system::error_code error;
        socket_.connect(endpoint, error);
        if (error) { throw boost::system::system_error(error); }
        else{
            std::cout << "Connection to " << host_ << ":" << port_ << " Successfully made!" << std::endl;
            isConnected_ = true;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Connection failed (Error: " << e.what() << ')' << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ConnectionHandler::getBytes(char bytes[], unsigned int bytesToRead) {
    size_t tmp = 0;
    boost::system::error_code error;
    try {
        while (!error && bytesToRead > tmp ) {
            tmp += socket_.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(bytes+tmp, bytesToRead-tmp), error);
        }
        if(error) { throw boost::system::system_error(error); }
    } 
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "recv failed (Error: " << e.what() << ')' << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ConnectionHandler::sendBytes(const char bytes[], int bytesToWrite) {
    int tmp = 0;
    boost::system::error_code error;
    try {
        while (!error && bytesToWrite > tmp ) {
            tmp += socket_.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(bytes + tmp, bytesToWrite - tmp), error);
        }
        if(error) { throw boost::system::system_error(error); }
    } 
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "recv failed (Error: " << e.what() << ')' << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ConnectionHandler::getLine(std::string& line) { return getFrameAscii(line, '\n'); }

bool ConnectionHandler::sendLine(std::string& line) { return sendFrameAscii(line, '\n'); }

bool ConnectionHandler::getFrameAscii(std::string& frame, char delimiter) {
    char ch;
    do{
        if(!getBytes(&ch, 1)) { return false; }
        frame.append(1, ch);
    }while (delimiter != ch);
    return true;
}

bool ConnectionHandler::sendFrameAscii(const std::string& frame, char delimiter) {
    bool result=sendBytes(frame.c_str(),frame.length());
    if(!result) return false;
    return sendBytes(&delimiter,1);
}

// Close down the connection properly.
void ConnectionHandler::close() {
    try{
        socket_.close();
        isConnected_ = false;
    } 
    catch (...) { std::cout << "closing failed: connection already closed" << std::endl; }
}

bool ConnectionHandler::isConnected(){ return isConnected_; }
```

makefile:

```
# All Targets
all: client

# Tool invocations
# Executable "client" depends on the files Client.o, ConnectionHandler.o.
client: bin/Client.o bin/ConnectionHandler.o
    @echo 'Building target: client'
    @echo 'Invoking: C++ Linker'
    g++ -o bin/client bin/Client.o bin/ConnectionHandler.o -lboost_system -lboost_locale -lboost_thread
    @echo 'Finished building target: client'
    @echo ' '

# Depends on the source and header files
bin/Client.o: src/Client.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -c -Linclude -I/usr/local/boost/1.57.0/include/boost -o bin/Client.o src/Client.cpp

# Depends on the source and header files 
bin/ConnectionHandler.o: src/ConnectionHandler.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -Linclude -o bin/ConnectionHandler.o src/ConnectionHandler.cpp


.PHONY: clean
#Clean the build directory
clean: 
    rm -f bin/*
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: ***/usr/local/boost/1.57.0/include/boost*** That does not look like a windows path. Are you using cygwin??

Comment: Do you use g++ on Windows, or Microsoft compiler?

Comment: Look at the compiler command that make prints, that gets an error.  Cut and paste that command line to your shell prompt.  Does it fail the same way?  If so, there's nothing wrong with your makefile.

Comment: dreschrjm, you right. It seems that I have a problem with my windows path. I also rechecked the program and saw that I have problems with including thread.hpp and locale.hpp as well. All those files are in this path: C:\Boost\include\boost-1_59\boost. How can I include it correctly (tried to play with it, didn't succeed)?